# How to query inside field value of Products in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to add **onSnapshot** individual fields like products, and transactions?
I want to get individual data field(products) with query.

```
const docRef = doc(db, 'user', user.uid);
  const unsub = onSnapshot(doc(db, 'user', user.uid), (doc) => {
    console.log('Current data: ', doc.data().products);
  });
```

It's always run when bio, transactions change. But I want this function to run only when products are added or deleted.

[image: Firestore data]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but in general: 1) All client-side Firestore SDKs (such as the one for client-side JavaScript) retrieve full documents with all fields. 2) You can [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to retrieve only certain documents from a collection. 3) But if you already know the ID of the document, it's faster to use that to retrieve the document as you already do.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore listener are all about document change like any field of document changed then listener called, So there is two way.

1. Detect `only when products are added or deleted` on client-side for single document listener.
2. Put `products` and `bio` in separate document.